# PDO Issues both with and without ' ' around placeholders

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
    try {
    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE full_name = :username");
    $STH->bindParam(':username', $username); 
    $nameExists = $STH->rowCount(); 
    if ($nameExists != 0) {
        $error .= "That username already exists<br>";
    }
}

    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        $error .= $e->getMessage()  . "<br>";
    }
```

The above is the code I am using. $username is defined earlier on. The issue with this code is I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username' at
>   line 1

When I change the code to include ' around :username  so...

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE full_name = ':username'");
```

The statement executes fine but doesn't match records when it should be. When I remove the placeholder and just write WHERE full_name = 'John Doe' everything works fine.

Any help in resolving this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you mean `prepare()` instead of `query()`?

Comment: I wonder, if you followed the php manual about this.. where did you see that `query` accepts named parameters? Or is it that the difference between a query and prepared statement is what confuses you?

Comment: I've literally just started looking at PDO over mysql_ today. I copied the query from code on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ when they check row count.

Comment: @LearningPHP - the tutorial contains tons of errors, basically what you did is equivalent to `mysql_query('SELECT id FROM...')` but if you use named parameters then use what Sam posted as the answer.

Comment: It was in fact the difference between query / prepare that threw me. As a side question - is there any advantage of query over prepare? Am I right in thinking that query() doesn't protect against SQL Injections like prepare() does?

Comment: `query` sends a regular query, no escaping done. `prepare` makes MySQL "compile" (lex actually) the query so you can execute multiple times with different parameters. That means the parsing is done once, then you just feed the query with parameters. It's useful for doing things such as inserts from a loop etc. The difference is that  `prepare` has to be executed by `execute`, which will call PDO's `quote` function, which takes care of string sanitizing depending on the database engine and other factors. Basically, query is unsafe, prepare is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE full_name = :username");
$STH->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
```

With bindParam:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE full_name = :username");
$STH->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
```